# Rows not being updated

Tags: c#, database, setting

I have written the following function meant to update a student in my database:

```
public bool UpdateStudent(Student stu)
{
   Console.WriteLine("StudentManger.UpdateStudent): Called");

   int rowsChanged = 0;

   using (var cnn = new SqlConnection(
          Properties.Settings.Default.universityConnectionString))
   {
      using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Student " +
              "SET FirstName = @FirstName, " +
              "lastName = @LastName, " +
              "birth = @birth " +
              "WHERE id = @id", cnn))
      {
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FirstName", stu.FirstName));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@LastName", stu.LastName));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id", stu.ID));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@birth", stu.Birth));

        cnn.Open();
        rowsChanged = (int)cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
      }
    }
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    return (rowsChanged != 0);
  }
```

But when I call  function no data is actually getting saved to the Database

Can someone tell me why?

Comment: You're leaving out a lot of helpful information for people to be able to help you. Can you provide more details?

Comment: I don't think it's a bad question. Just might be sooo many different things going wrong with your app that it'll be hard to troubleshoot IMO.

Comment: (I agree with @frenchie.)  Is an exception being thrown?  Are you connecting to the correct database?  Is it loading the correct connection string?  What have you tried?

Comment: Why are you typecasting an int to an int? You also forgot to close the connection. I'm with frenchie on this one.

Comment: I think you should try your connection first with a simple read query. What happens when you load everything from the table? If that works, then at least we'll know it's not a connection problem.

Comment: I can Getdata by using the same connection and show it to GridView in Form

and when I call updateStudent The data in GrideView well Changed But doesn't save to DataBase

Comment: Is this wrapped in a `try...catch` that is swallowing exceptions or something? Can you step through it and see that nothing blows up? Does the account under which the update is being run have permissions to update the db?

Comment: what database engine are you using? sometimes when you use sql express for example it gets copied into bin and gets updated when you execute your app. while you are looking at your project's database file. Also, have you got any transaction scope overt this function call. It might have got rolled back at some stage.

Comment: How I can explain ??

No save to Physical file in dataBase 
just in Propertis........

Comment: We get that it's not updating the database, we're trying to figure out *why* it's not updating the database.  Can you try stepping through the code and reporting back what happens?

Comment: Is there any another Code to Connect to dataBase 
without using Properties.

Comment: So, finally rowsChanged is equals to 0?

Comment: That means the update happened. Are you reading and writing with the same database?  Can you profile the database and see the transactions going through? Are you saving the old data and then updating the in-memory object?

Comment: yes i can update it in memory object and insert and retrive it but doesn't save to database

Comment: I'm asking about the order of operations, not *if* you can do it. If you're updating the database with old values, it will appear to not update.  Can you step through and make sure the right values are making it to your method?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by your comment. If the values are correct when you step through, can you explain what makes you think your updates aren't going through? What have you tried?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11666/discussion-between-james-dangelo-and-aahn)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the entire solution and information you provided in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11666/discussion-between-james-dangelo-and-aahn), your code is fine.  The problem is that the .mdf database file is set to "Copy to Output Directory": "Always" in your project. Change this property to "Copy if newer" (or "Do not copy" and move it to the bin folder yourself) and it will not overwrite your changes when you re-run the application. Importantly, you *will not* see the changes you make in your application reflected in your .mdf database file *in the project's root directory*. It actually gets copied to the /bin folder and that's where the changes are persisted.  So, if you don't change the "Copy to Output Directory" property, it will copy from your root to your /bin folder every time you build. Thus it *appears* that the changes aren't being persisted, when they actually are.